# Julia DataFrame Fill NA with LOCF

Tags: dataframe, julia

Is there any fast way to convert a DataFrame's NA values to the last observed value?

```
using DataFrames

d = @data [1,NA,5,NA,NA]
df = DataFrame(d=d)

result = filled_with_locf(df)

expected = [1,1,5,5,5]
```

- LOCF = Last Observation Carried Forward

Comment: `result = d[cummax([i*!isna(d[i]) for i=1:length(d)])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment oneliner, if we define `locf` as:

```
locf(v) = v[cummax([i*!isna(v[i]) for i=1:length(v)])]
```

Then,

```
nona_df = DataFrame(Any[locf(df[c]) for c in names(df)],names(df))
```

And,

```
julia> nona_df
5×1 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ d │
├─────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 1 │
│ 3   │ 5 │
│ 4   │ 5 │
│ 5   │ 5 │
```

Comment: where is this isna function defined?

Comment: @xgdgsc This is for an older version of DataFrames. Perhaps currently `ismissing` takes the job if `isna` and `missing` is the new `NA`

Comment: wasn't able to find cummax in julia 1.3.1. Ended up using `accumulate`. 
`locf(v) = v[accumulate(max, [i*!ismissing(v[i]) for i=1:length(v)])]`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid BoundsError when the first value of the column is missing, use init=1 in accumulate function call.

```
locf(v) = v[accumulate(max, [i* !(ismissing(v[i])|isnan(v[i])) for i in 1:length(v)], init = 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Julia and don't understand why [Dan Getz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198219/13716814) worked, check out [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68152605/13716814) in a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58722185/13716814).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this:

This should work too although might need to adjust it for your specific case. This is taking into consideration only positive numbers in the array.

```
function locf(x::Array{Float64})
dx = zeros(x)
for i in 2:length(x)-1
    if x[i+1] > 0 && x[i] == 0.0
        dx[i+1] = x[i+1]
    end
        if dx[i] == 0 
            dx[i] = dx[i-1]
        end
    end
    return dx
end

    na_locf = locf(dummy_array)
```