# What's an efficient way to fill `missing` values with previous non-missing value?

Tags: julia

I have a vector

```
using Missings
v = allowmissing(rand(100))
v[rand(100) .< 0.1] .= missing
```

what's the best way to fill `v` with the last non-missing value?

Currently

```
for (i, val) in enumerate(v)
  ismissing(val) && (i >=2) && (v[i]=v[i-1])
end
first_non_missing = findfirst(x->!ismissing(x), v)
if first_non_missing >= 2
  v[1:first_non_missing -1] .= v[first_non_missing]
end
v = disallowmissing(v)
```

But I found it to be slow for large vectors. What's an elegant and efficient way to fill missing values with previous non-missing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and fast solution:

```
replace_missing!(v) = accumulate!((n0,n1) -> ismissing(n1) ? n0 : n1, v, v, init=zero(eltype(v)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you need an init value in case the fist value is missing, and i can't execute your code. but with that said, here is my attempt:

```
function replace_missing!(v,init=zero(eltype(v)))
    function reduce_missing(n0,n1)
        if ismissing(n1)
            return n0
        else
            return n1
        end
    end
    v[1] = reduce_missing(init,v[1])
    for i = 2:length(v)
        v[i] = reduce_missing(v[i-1],v[i])
    end
return v
end
using Missings
v = allowmissing(rand(100))
v[rand(100) .< 0.1] .= missing
v = replace_missing!(v)
v = disallowmissing(v)
```

Comment: my solution is working now.  NOt sure if it's more efficient though.

Comment: your solution seems faster in my preliminary tests :(

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is entirely based on the discussions in this thread: [Julia DataFrame Fill NA with LOCF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41196748/13716814). More specifically, it is based on the answers by Danish Shrestha, [Dan Getz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198219/13716814), and [btsays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67465356/13716814).

As [laborg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58724665/13716814) implies, the [accumulate](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.accumulate) function in Base Julia will do the job.

Suppose we have an array: a = [1, missing, 2, missing, 9]. We want to replace the 1st `missing` with `1` and the second with `2`: a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 9], which is `a = a[[1, 1, 3, 3, 5]]` ([1, 1, 3, 3, 5] here are indexes).

This function will do the job:

```
ffill(v) = v[accumulate(max, [i*!ismissing(v[i]) for i in 1:length(v)], init=1)]
```

BTW, "ffill" means "forward filling", a name I adopted from Pandas.

I'll explain in the following.

What the `accumulate` function does is that it returns a new array based on the array we input.

For those of you who are new to Julia like me: in Julia's mathematical operations, `i*true = i`, and `i*false=0`. Therefore, when an element in the array is NOT missing, then `i*!ismissing() = i`; otherwise,  `i*!ismissing() = 0`.

In the case of a = [1, missing, 2, missing, 9], `[i*!ismissing(a[i]) for i in 1:length(a)]` will return `[1, 0, 3, 0, 5]`. Since this array is in the `accumulate` function where the operation is `max`, we'll get `[1, 1, 3, 3, 5]`.

Then `a[[1, 1, 3, 3, 5]]` will return `[1, 1, 2, 2, 9]`.

That's why

```
a = ffill(a)
```

will get `[1, 1, 2, 2, 9]`.

Now, you may wonder why we have `init = 1` in `ffill(v)`. Say, `b = [missing, 1, missing, 3]`. Then, `[i*!ismissing(b[i]) for i in 1:length(b)]` will return `[0, 2, 0, 4]`. Then the `accumulate` function will return [0, 2, 2, 4]. The next step, b[[0, 2, 2, 4]] will throw an error because in Julia, index starts from `1` not `0`. Therefore, b[0] doesn't mean anything.

With `init = 1` in the `accumulate` function, we'll get [1, 2, 2, 4] rather than [0, 2, 2, 4] since 1 (the `init` we set) is larger than 0 (the first number).

We can go further form here. The `ffill()` function above only works for a single array. But what if we have a large dataframe?

Say, we have:

```
using DataFrames

a = ["Tom", "Mike", "John", "Jason", "Bob"]
b = [missing, 2, 3, missing, 8]
c = [1, 3, missing, 99, missing]
df = DataFrame(:Name => a, :Var1 => b, :Var2 => c)
```

```
julia> df

5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Name    Var1     Var2    
     │ String  Int64?   Int64?  
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │ Tom     missing        1
   2 │ Mike          2        3
   3 │ John          3  missing 
   4 │ Jason   missing       99
   5 │ Bob           8  missing
```

Here, [Dan Getz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198219/13716814) comes in handy:

```
nona_df = DataFrame([ffill(df[!, c]) for c in names(df)], names(df))
```

```
julia> nona_df 

5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Name    Var1     Var2   
     │ String  Int64?   Int64? 
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │ Tom     missing       1
   2 │ Mike          2       3
   3 │ John          3       3
   4 │ Jason         3      99
   5 │ Bob           8      99
```